# Github not letting me download my own projects anymore

Tags: git, github

I am trying to do git pull from terminal and I get the following error.  I haven't changed anything on my machine and it worked before without any issues? I did download the github client app, would that of changed my permissions?

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Comment: Downloaded ***which*** GitHub client app, the Windows or Mac version?

Answer (score 0):

The github client app shouldn't have changed your permissions, but maybe it changed something in your `.ssh/config` or your public key.